# Function to test for different conditions in input data

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have the following function that checks a data record to see if it has met certain criteria specified separately in configuration settings. The configurations are set up as a list of dictionaries with certain trigger keywords that are used by the condition check function ('in','not in', etc).

The condition checker has a lot of duplicated code, but it's just different enough that a better setup is not obvious to me. I would appreciate any feedback.

Here is a minimal working example to illustrate:

```
def check_if_condition_was_met( row, condition ):
    condition_met = True
    for key, val in condition.iteritems():
        if key == 'in':
            for condition_key, condition_val in val.iteritems():
                if row[condition_key] in condition_val:  # IN
                    continue
                else:
                    condition_met = False
                    break
        elif key == 'not in':               
            for condition_key, condition_val in val.iteritems():
                if row[condition_key] not in condition_val:  # NOT IN
                    continue
                else:
                    condition_met = False
                    break
        elif key == 'max':         
            for condition_key, condition_val in val.iteritems():
                if not row[condition_key]:
                    condition_met = False
                    break
                if int(row[condition_key]) <= int(condition_val): # MAX (<=)
                    continue
                else:
                    condition_met = False
                    break
        elif key == 'min':
            for condition_key, condition_val in val.iteritems():
                if int(row[condition_key]) >= int(condition_val): # MIN (>=)
                    continue
                else:
                    condition_met = False
                    break
    return condition_met


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # data
    test_data = [
         {'Flag1':'Y', 'Flag2':'Canada','Number':35}
        ,{'Flag1':'Y', 'Flag2':'United States','Number':35}
        ,{'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'United States','Number':35}
        ,{'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'England','Number':35}
        ,{'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'Canada','Number':35}
        ,{'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'Canada','Number':5}
    ]

    # configuration
    test_conditions = [
         { 'in':{'Flag1':['N'], 'Flag2':['United States']} }
        ,{ 'in':{'Flag1':['Y'],'Flag2':['Canada']}, 'max':{'Number':7} }
        ,{ 'in':{'Flag1':['Y'],'Flag2':['Canada']}, 'min':{'Number':7} }
        ,{ 'not in':{'Flag1':['Y']}, 'min':{'Number':7} }
    ]

    for condition_id, condition in enumerate(test_conditions):
        print
        print 'now testing for condition %i' % condition_id
        for data_id, data in enumerate(test_data):
            print '%s | %s' % ( data_id, check_if_condition_was_met(data,condition) )
```

Comment: It's still very vague - lots of my functions test for different conditions of their input data.  Can you make it any more specific?  I can see that it's difficult, because the function does seem to be a "big switch" (and obviously we want to improve on that).  What's the code being used *for*?  Is it part of a test suite?  Or is it some utility you're making?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to @Peilonrayz, I would map each of the comparators to a function, but I'd go further.

- **Function design:** `check_if_condition_was_met(…)` is an awkward name, partly because of the unusual use of past tense.  But why make it so wordy?  Couldn't you just call it `verify(…)`?

  Furthermore, it would be customary to put the `condition` parameter first, and the `row` second.  It would certainly read more naturally in English, especially after the function rename.  Also, based on the observation that `verify(condition)` could be considered as a test, it's a general [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming) principle that the [`condition` parameter should be considered more tightly associated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) with the verification process and should therefore be put first.
- **Use `all(…)`:**  You want to express the idea that a function should return `True` if all of the conditions must be met, and `False` if any condition fails.  You can do that using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).   It's a lot less cumbersome than your `condition_met`, `for`, `continue`, and `break`.  The entire function can be simplified down to a single expression!
- **Naming:**  I think that "key" and "val" are not quite descriptive enough.  I suggest the following renamings:

  `key` → `comparator`
  `val` → `criteria`
  `condition_key` → `key`
  `condition_val` → `desired_val`

I'm also skeptical about some of the behaviour when given anomalous input:

- **Why are there [`int(…)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) casts with `'min'` and `'max'`?**  Is it for parsing strings as numbers?  None of your example cases needs such parsing, though.  Is it for truncating floats towards zero?  Probably not, but it might have that unintended effect, if the thresholds or data are already numeric.
- **What happens if the row is missing a key that is specified in the condition?**  Maybe it's not a concern to you, but it might be more appropriate to have the function return `False` rather than raise a `KeyError`, as your code does?

**Consider writing [doctests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html)** to explain what the function does.  This is a situation where examples are more expressive than words.

### Suggested solution

```
COMPARATORS = {
    'in':       lambda v, lst: v in lst,
    'not in':   lambda v, lst: v not in lst,
    'min':      lambda v, n: (v is not None) and (v >= n),
    'max':      lambda v, n: (v is not None) and (v <= n),
}

def verify(condition, row):
    """
    Verify that the specified criteria are all true for the given row.

    >>> rows = [
    ...     {'Flag1':'Y', 'Flag2':'Canada',        'Number':35},
    ...     {'Flag1':'Y', 'Flag2':'United States', 'Number':35},
    ...     {'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'United States', 'Number':35},
    ...     {'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'England',       'Number':35},
    ...     {'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'Canada',        'Number':35},
    ...     {'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'Canada',        'Number':5},
    ... ]

    >>> [verify({'in': {'Flag1': ['N'], 'Flag2': ['United States']}}, r)
    ...  for r in rows]
    [False, False, True, False, False, False]

    >>> [verify({'not in': {'Flag1': ['Y']}, 'min': {'Number': 7}}, r)
    ...  for r in rows]
    [False, False, True, True, True, False]

    >>> [verify({'not in': {'Blah': ['whatever']}}, r) for r in rows]
    [True, True, True, True, True, True]
    """
    return all(
        all(
            COMPARATORS[comparator](row.get(key), desired_val)
            for key, desired_val in criteria.iteritems()
        )
        for comparator, criteria in condition.iteritems()
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `return` to also return early. It's easier to understand and read then assigning to `condition_met` and `break`.
2. I'm ignoring the extra code that `key = 'max'` has.
3. Your code would be smaller and easier to read if you inverted all your ifs.
4. You need to check what the similarities between each if is:

   ```
   if row[condition_key] in condition_val:  # IN
   if row[condition_key] not in condition_val:  # NOT IN
   if int(row[condition_key]) <= int(condition_val): # MAX (<=)
   if int(row[condition_key]) >= int(condition_val): # MIN (>=)
   ```

   From this we should see that you use one of four operators in each if. `in`, `not in`, `<=` and `>=`.
   You also cast the input into `int` on two of your ifs. To add this we can change each to cast to a type.

   Checking the operators that we need against the [`operator` comparison table](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) we can see we need:

   - `contains`
   - `le`
   - `ge`
   - And one for not contains.

   And so we can use:

   ```
   FUNCTIONS = {
       'in': (operator.contains, list),
       'not in': (lambda a, b: a not in b, list),
       'max': (operator.le, int),
       'min': (operator.ge, int),
   }
   ```

```
import operator

FUNCTIONS = {
    'in': (operator.contains, list),
    'not in': (lambda a, b: a not in b, list),
    'max': (operator.le, int),
    'min': (operator.ge, int),
}


def check_if_condition_was_met(row, condition):
    for key, val in condition.iteritems():
        op, cast = FUNCTIONS[key]
        for condition_key, condition_val in val.iteritems():
            if not op(cast(row[condition_key]), cast(condition_val)):
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: thanks for the really helpful feedback! I'll have to dig into your suggestions more carefully. But my first impression is that the output of your refactored version do not match my current setup? For example, test_data[2] and condition[0] was True, but now False (I think True is the right answer). Anyways, the concept is clear - I will look at studying it more carefully.

Comment: The bug is that [`operator.contains(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.contains) is equivalent to `b in a` — note the reversed operands. Confounding the discovery of the bug is the inappropriate use of the `list()` cast on both operands.

Comment: @200_success They're annoying, I for some reason didn't think of the `list` error too, but your answer cleans all of that down.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_if_condition_was_met( row, condition ):
    condition_met = True
    for key, val in condition.iteritems():
        if key == 'in':
            for condition_key, condition_val in val.iteritems():
            """Since continuing on 'in' and only manipulating 'not in's"""
                if row[condition_key] not in condition_val:
                    condition_met = False
                    break
        elif key == 'not in':               
            for condition_key, condition_val in val.iteritems():
            """Again continuing on 'not in' only manipulating 'in's"""
                if row[condition_key] in condition_val: 
                    condition_met = False
                    break
        elif key == 'max':         
            for condition_key, condition_val in val.iteritems():
                if not row[condition_key]:
                    condition_met = False
                    break
                """Same can  eliminate the the continue statements by changing this """
                elif int(row[condition_key]) >= int(condition_val): # elif 
                    condition_met = False
                    break
        elif key == 'min':
            for condition_key, condition_val in val.iteritems():
            """Again only manipulating the '<=' reached by else"""
                if int(row[condition_key]) <= int(condition_val): 
                    condition_met = False
                    break
    return condition_met


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # data
    test_data = [
         {'Flag1':'Y', 'Flag2':'Canada','Number':35}
        ,{'Flag1':'Y', 'Flag2':'United States','Number':35}
        ,{'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'United States','Number':35}
        ,{'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'England','Number':35}
        ,{'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'Canada','Number':35}
        ,{'Flag1':'N', 'Flag2':'Canada','Number':5}
    ]

    # configuration
    test_conditions = [
         { 'in':{'Flag1':['N'], 'Flag2':['United States']} }
        ,{ 'in':{'Flag1':['Y'],'Flag2':['Canada']}, 'max':{'Number':7} }
        ,{ 'in':{'Flag1':['Y'],'Flag2':['Canada']}, 'min':{'Number':7} }
        ,{ 'not in':{'Flag1':['Y']}, 'min':{'Number':7} }
    ]

    for condition_id, condition in enumerate(test_conditions):
        # print? is this being used for a newline? if so remove and add \n to next print
        print('\nnow testing for condition %i' % condition_id) #newline ()'s for print
        for data_id, data in enumerate(test_data):
            print('%s | %s' % ( data_id, check_if_condition_was_met(data,condition) ))
            #wrap print with ()'s again
```

Here are some things I would look at that can be done to get to the values you are altering more efficiently

Comment: Please fix your indentation of your added commentary.

Comment: Will do when I can return to my computer

Comment: @200_success could you please clairy, I may not be familiar with proper format for  indentation of comments